# Calling type-bound procedure for an array of derrived types in Fortran

Tags: oop, fortran, derived-class

Let's assume that I have a derived type `Coordinates` with its type-bound procedure `swap`:

```
module myTypes
    implicit none
    public :: Coordinates  

    type Coordinates
        real :: x,y
    contains
        procedure :: swap  ! Error here
    end type
contains
    subroutine swap(this)
        class (Coordinates) :: this
        this%x = this%x + this%y
        this%y = -(this%y - this%x)
        this%x = this%x - this%y
    end subroutine
end module
```

Now, if I have an instance of `Coordinates` called `point_A`, and if I want to call the type-bound procedure `swap` for it, I would just write: `call point_A%swap`. But if I have an array of instances of `Coordinates`, like:

```
type(Coordinates), dimension(:), allocatable :: setOfPoints
```

then to call the `swap` for all the elements of `setOfPoints`, I would like to write:

```
call setOfPoints(:)%swap
```

In order to achieve that, I change the code of `swap` procedure to:

```
subroutine swap(these)
        class (Coordinates), dimension(:)  :: these
        integer :: i
        do i = 1, size(this)
            this(i)%x = this(i)%x + this(i)%y
            this(i)%y = -(this(i)%y - this(i)%x)
            this(i)%x = this(i)%x - this(i)%y
        end do
end subroutine
```

Unfortunately, gfortran doesn't like my idea. On the line that I marked in the first piece of code it says:

```
Error: Passed-object dummy argument of 'swap' must be scalar.
```

Question: how can I call the type-bound procedure for all the instances of the derived type at once? I don't want to put the call in the loop, but I want to do this as I wrote it before, like what we always do with arrays in Fortran.

I read about the `ELEMENTAL` keyword, but if I want to use it, I need the type-bound procedure to be 'pure', which is not my case. 
I tried to place a `DEFERRED` keyword after the word `procedure`, but then compiler says:

```
Error: Interface must be specified for DEFERRED binding
```

I created an interface for `swap`, but I couldn't figure out where to place it. I tried many positions and compiler said that 'interface was unexpected there'.
Also, I read about `SELECT TYPE`, but I think it won't help in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific example is perfectly fine with ELEMENTAL

```
module myTypes
    implicit none
    public :: Coordinates  

    type Coordinates
        real :: x,y
    contains
        procedure :: swap  ! Error here
    end type
contains
    elemental subroutine swap(this)
        class (Coordinates), intent(inout) :: this
        this%x = this%x + this%y
        this%y = -(this%y - this%x)
        this%x = this%x - this%y
    end subroutine

end module

 use myTypes

 type(Coordinates) :: arr(10)

 arr = Coordinates(1.,2.)

 call arr%swap

 end
```

Your subroutine is pure. If it cannot be, consider using `impure elemental`.

Comment: Thank you very much! `impure elemental` worked fine for me!                P.S.: indeed, here I omitted some lines that made the subroutine impure